# Facing problem to show properly sub-categories in the Categories Dropdown list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, e-commerce

Troubling problem to show **sub-categories** in the **Categories** Dropdown list

in my code,i want to **show category** and **sub catagory** under the **Category** in the **Products table**.

Here is my **categories table**

**1.**

```
 public function up() { Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('parent_id'); //sub category id
    $table->string('name');  
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Here is my **products table**

**2.**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is my **Category Mode**l

**3.Category.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model { protected $guarded=[];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','parent_id','id');
    }
}
```

Here is my **Product Model**

**4.Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->hasone('App\Category');
    }

}
```

Now here is my **ProductsController.php**

**5.ProductsController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public  function product(){
         return view('admin.products.product');
     }


}
```

Here is my **product.blade.php** file

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('add.product')}}" name="add_product" id="add_product" novalidate="novalidate">
                                @csrf

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Under Category </label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;"  >
                                            <option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>
                                           @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}"  >
                                                    {{ $cat->parent ? $cat->parent->name .' -- ' : '' }}
                                                    {{$cat->name}}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I want to data like this
[image: what i want]

thats why i use this code **product.blade.php**

```
 @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}"  >
                                                    {{ $cat->parent ? $cat->parent->name .' -- ' : '' }}
                                                    {{$cat->name}}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach
```

but i get data like this, which i donot want :-
[image: i get data like this]

Comment: Side note: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');` would be correct relation in `Product` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
@foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
 <option value="{{$cat->id}}"  >
  {{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->parent->name }}
 </option>
@endforeach
```

I think the result would be something like this.
If not has parent render category `$cat->parent->name`.
If has parent render sub-category `'--' . $cat->name`.

```
Shoes
-- Casual Shoes
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: If you work with categories and subcategories in Laravel, I recommend you use closure table. https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable good luck!

Comment: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: if i user your code it get an error like that                                                             
  **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\product.blade.php)**

Comment: @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}"  >
                                                    {{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->parent->name }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endforeach

Comment: @TareqAhmed Hi, could you show me which of the two is giving error `$cat->parent->name` or `$cat->name`.

Answer (score 1):

**Category.php** - add child relation

```
public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category','id','parent_id');
}
```

**product.blade.php**

```
<select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;"  >
  <option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>
      @foreach(App\Category::where('parent_id', 0)->get() as $parent)
          <option value="{{$parent->id}}">
              {{ $parent->name }}
          </option>
          @foreach($parent->children as $child)
              <option value="{{$child->id}}">
                  -- {{$child->name}}
              </option>
          @endforeach
       @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: if i user your code it get an error like that                                                                  **Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\product.blade.php)**

Comment: @TareqAhmed In the answer from wheesnoza you will have such a problem that if your parents repeat, if they have different positions in the database

Comment: in case of your code , only category comes, sub category is not coming